# TDBListView and TAdvDBListView - showing icons to the items

Tags: delphi

I am stuck with TDBListView and TAdvDBListView and the way to display icons with the displayed items.
I have connected them to ImageList, but i cant find property which to drive connection of the ImageList - image index and the fields which is displayed,
or i am missing something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create custom renders for the rows and colums. 
This is the normal solution in the most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I found that i need to draw the object manually with the refresh of the elements :'|
I have expected something more suffisticated :|